# Use UNPIVOT and increment number column by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the below query that I am using `UNPIVOT` function to transform the `FREIGHT_AMT` column and `SALETX_AMT` value as additional rows under the `MERCHANDISE_AMT` column. This seems to work as expected, however the `Row_Number()` function is causing some issues with the `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` because the `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` does not always start with 1. I need the subsequent unpivoted rows to return whatever the `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` + 1. So for example if I have a `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of 1, then the subsequent unpivoted row should show a `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of 2. If I have a `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of 5, then the subsequent unpivoted row should show a `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of 6.

```
    WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                             
          THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END AS UnNamedColumn, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, C.FREIGHT_AMT, C.SALETX_AMT

FROM  PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND DD.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID AND DD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND DD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE 
C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
--AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '90059'
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
AND A.VOUCHER_ID = '00720667'
)

SELECT INVOICE_ID,Row_Number() over(order by INVOICE_ID) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,UnNamedColumn,value
FROM CTE
unpivot (value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)) u
WHERE value > 0.00
```

**Here is a sample of my data (non-pivoted):**

```
INVOICE_ID      VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    UnNamedColumn   MERCHANDISE_AMT   FREIGHT_AMT   SALETX_AMT
1100000720667   1                   MISCELLANEOUS   17480.820         59.540        233.380
5000000641893   5                   ITEM            568.120           8.160         83.920
1800000972341   2                   ITEM            76.710            0.00          0.00
```

**Desired output (unpivoted and VOUCHER_LINE_NUM incrementing appropriately):**

```
 INVOICE_ID      VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    UnNamedColumn   value
 1100000720667   1                   MISCELLANEOUS   17480.820
 1100000720667   2                   MISCELLANEOUS   59.540
 1100000720667   3                   MISCELLANEOUS   233.380
 5000000641893   5                   MISCELLANEOUS   568.120
 5000000641893   6                   MISCELLANEOUS   8.160
 5000000641893   7                   MISCELLANEOUS   83.920
 1800000972341   2                   MISCELLANEOUS   76.710
 (End)
```

`INVOICE_ID` `1100000720667` has a `VOUCHER_LINE__NUM` of `1` , so therefore the subsequent unpivoted rows for `FREIGHT_AMT` and `SALETX_AMT` have `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of `2` and `3`, respectfully. `INVOICE_ID` `5000000641893` has a `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of `5`, so therefore the subsequent unpivoted rows for `FREIGHT_AMT` and `SALETX_AMT` have `VOUCHER_LINE_NUM` of `6` and `7`, respectfully.

**EDIT:**

I edited  the code below to include the `PARTITION` however I am seeing an issue for rows where there is no `FREIGHT_AMT` or `SALETX_AMT` it is incrementing the columns incorrectly, beginning with the 2nd row. In this case I should have VOUCHER_LINE_NUM 1 - 24 but it is incrementing by 2 for each row i.e. 1,3,5,7, etc...

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                             
          THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END AS UnNamedColumn, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, C.FREIGHT_AMT, C.SALETX_AMT

FROM  PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND DD.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID AND DD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND DD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE 
C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
--AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '90059'
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
  AND A.VOUCHER_ID = '00721021' )
--AND A.VOUCHER_ID IN ('00720667', '00721196', '00721021'))

SELECT INVOICE_ID,VOUCHER_LINE_NUM - 1 + row_number() over (PARTITION BY INVOICE_ID ORDER BY INVOICE_ID) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,UnNamedColumn,value
FROM CTE
unpivot (value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)) u

WHERE value > 0.00
```

Comment: Just add `ROW_NUMBER - 1` (obviously with the correct `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: I edited the post above with my updated code, however the VOUCHER_LINE_NUM is incrementing by 2 for INVOICE_ID's where I don't need it to unpivot (SALETX_AMT and FREIGHT_AMT) are both 0.00

Comment: `PARTITION BY INVOICE_ID ORDER BY INVOICE_ID` doesn't make any sense. Ordering and partitioning on the same column means that the ordering is completely arbitrary. The `ORDER BY` and `PARTITION BY` clauses should contain different columns. Also, stating the value is incrementing by 2 doesn't make a lot of sense, as `ROW_NUMBER` only increments by 1. We, however, can't run your SQL as you provide no sample data for us to execute it against.

Comment: I don't get the logic of the numbering, please explain